# References or resource recommendation for mapping of 1D spinless Hubbard model into XXZ Heisenberg model

Tags: condensed-matter, ising-model, lattice-model, spin-models, spin-chains

I read from somewhere that 1D spinless Hubbard model can be mapped onto XXZ Heisenberg model but I don't remember from where did I read this sentence. I tried googling it but couldn't find any thing in which somebody is explaining it.

Please recommend me some books or other resources in which somebody has explained this mapping in details.

Comment: "Jordan-Wigner transformation" is what you want

Comment: @RubenVerresen do you know any references in which someone has applied this transformation to Hubbard model in a pedagogical way?

Comment: just plug in $c^\dagger_n = \sigma^z_1 \cdots \sigma^z_{n-1} \sigma^+_n$ and it'll drop out